# Counterexample : the union of path connected space is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm looking  for a counterexample of two topopogical path connected spac is not path connected space.
Thanks

Comment: How about $S^1$ and $S^1 + (100,100)$?

Comment: This must be the easiest counterexample ever in all of mathematics. Now if you were asked to produce a union of two path-connected spaces which is connected but not path-connected...

Answer (score 1):

Consider in $\mathbb{R}$ this two sets: $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(2,3)$. Both are path connected, but the union $A\cup B = (0,1)\cup (2,3)$ is not path-connected. You cannot create a path that goes from 1/2 to 5/2, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\{0\}, B=\{1\}$. This is to reach a 30 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\{(x,sin(\frac{1}{x})); x \in \mathbb{R^+}\}$ and $B=\{(0,x);0\leq x \leq 1\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are path connected but $A\cup B$ is not path connected despite it being a connected set (look for *Topologist's sine curve*).